# How to use gnosis relay api to send TX

Tags: signature, gnosis-safe, gnosis

i am trying to use `relayer service`. But when i use the `safe{address}/transactions` api to exec transaction the `signatures` is required type int.
I don't know how to create signature forthis. Pls help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `signatures` is an array of signature objects that are defined as 3 integers (`v`, `r`, `s`). When handling ECDSA signatures this is always the case, just that in most cases `r` and `s` are represented by the hex representation of these (very large) integers. For this endpoint the relay service actually expects stringyfied integers for `r` and `s` (so `"1234"` instead of `1234`).

This service is not actively being developed, right now (only maintenance), therefore there is no extensive documentation.

Some existing examples/ docs are:

- [Relay demo](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-demo#transaction-execution)
- [Old service docs](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-docs/blob/devportal/docs/services_02_relay.md)

Comment: i understand thank you for the information